# Finding the loop invariant of selection sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, clrs

I am trying to find then loop invariant of selection sort

**Pseudo code**

```
SELECTION SORT (A,n)
for i= 1 to n-1
    smallest=i
    for j=i+1 to n
        if A[j]<A[smallest]
                smallest=j
    exchange A[i] with A[smallest]
```

My answer for the loop invariant, is that the subarray `A[1:i]` is always sorted and consists of the smallest elements of `A[1:n]`,however the official solution mentions that instead of `A[1:i]`, it will be `A[1:i-1]`.

Here's what I fail to understand, if the invariant is `A[1:i-1]`,then when `i=1` at initialization, we have `A[1:0]`. How does that make any sense? What does the subarray `A[1:0]` mean?
[Here's the link to the official solution](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/11599/selected-solutions.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The misunderstanding probably stems from what the *slice* notation `A[1:n]` means. As is often the case with pseudo code, arrays start at position 1, and such slices are *inclusive*, i.e. the end position belongs to the sub array. This is unlike how it works in many programming languages where indexing starts at 0 and slices *exclude* the final index (e.g. in Python).

We can see that the author intended to *include* the ending position from this phrase in the referenced document:

> the subarray A[1:─1] consists of the smallest ─1 elements

So, for example, in that notation `A[1:1]` is a sub array with one element (the first element), and thus `A[1:0]` denotes an empty sub array, which is indeed the initial situation when nothing is sorted yet.

Let's compare the two notations for an example array `A = [10, 20, 30]`

| Pseudo code with 1-based positions and range ending after end position | Python code with 0-based indexes and range ending before end index | Slice result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `A[1:3]` | `A[0:3]` | `[10, 20, 30]` |
| `A[1:2]` | `A[0:2]` | `[10, 20]` |
| `A[1:1]` | `A[0:1]` | `[10]` |
| `A[1:0]` | `A[0:0]` | `[]` |

Comment: If the array index begins at 1, shouldn’t A[1:0] indicate the subarray of A consisting of A[1] and A[0]?  Or will it just consist of A[0]? If so, why?

Comment: No, it represents an empty sub array. `A[1:3]` has 3 elements, `A[1:2]` has 2 elements, `A[1:1]` has 1 element, so by extrapolation, `A[1:0]` has 0 elements. It may look odd, but how else would you denote an empty slice with this notation?

Comment: Another way to reason is that in zero-based indexing languages (cf. Python slices) you would use one less for the start and consider the ending index as excluded from the range. Then you'd say `A[0:3]` has 3 elements, ... and `A[0:0]` has 0.